# How dynamically change the iconAlign in Extjs?

Tags: extjs

I have set a button like this:

```
  xtype: 'button',
  icon: 'icons/money_add.png',
  text: 'Details',
  iconAlign: 'left',
  scale: 'small',
```

I need to change the icon, iconAlign and scale based on some conditions

I managed to change the icon and the scale like this:

```
buttonPath('#buttonId').setIcon('icons/newIcon.png');
buttonPath('#buttonId').setScale('large');
```

I need to change the iconAlign from letf to top but it is not working

I have tried

```
buttonPath('#buttonId').setIconAlign('top');
```

and it didn't work. Is there any way to change it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button properies you mentioned are bindable.  Here is an example of using binding to change the values of buttons.  I bind to a boolean for hiding and showing buttons, makes it easy to make the buttons active based on other rules so you don't have to find the button and call a method when something in your app changes.

[Button Properties and Binding](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/39mo)

Comment: I had to made some changes to made it work like that but it works. Thanks